# TestNGException while executing mavenized selenium project from Command prompt

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, classpath, testng

I am running mavenized TestNG Webdriver project from command prompt using 'mvn clean install test' but I get the following exception in the cmd prompt

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
17:test (default-test) on project WebdriverWithTestNG: Execution default-test of
goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was
an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] An error occurred while instantiating class com.generic.validateorders.W
ebAppTest: null
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:398)
```

On the other hand whenever I run it from the eclipse it executes perfectly fine without any issues. Is there any issue with my project classpath? If yes then how do I fix it.

Comment: Is this the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @niharika: its a long stack trace, how do I share it. Basically it always shows up when I run the project using command prompt

Comment: What's happeninghere : com.generic.validateorders.W
ebAppTest: null

Comment: You can post the entire trace here - I don't think there should be an issue

Comment: @niharika: com.generic.validateorders.W ebAppTest: null ... I get this everytime I run project through command prompt but not through the eclipse.

Comment: @niharika: You may refer the following link for the stack trace: https://04876790186064025507.googlegroups.com/attach/e360fea61b0c7f52/Exception.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHLGcVZThgZo5KFNvfwsKGvWhDH_yRUBe__N3PgwGH2i1bMRUB_bRfdF4EUfJQQJpXA9Uevd9hUQDkjVEefqr_7HFrdbjxO9q2role1H5a-s1TZ7G8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63776/discussion-between-rishi-and-niharika-neo).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have fork mode set to never in your pom.xml for surefire plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
<forkMode>never</forkMode>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: -what is the use of forkMode and why isn't it required when running the project from eclipse

Comment: Forkmode is somethign you set if you want to run test in parallel for memory requirments. as far as eclipse is concerned eclise does not uses the surefire plugin to run testNG test cases. It has its own plugin. Since you are running your tests using Maven hence surefire plugin is required. More information on forkmode please visit http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: I already have the surefire in the maven pom.xml but still the I get the error while executing cases from command line

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>

Comment: have you tried configuration as I stated in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue.

**Root-Cause:**
Mistakenly I had removed target folder created by Maven, and I was trying to run pom.xml

Execution failed with below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project MoneyFlow: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process

**Solution**:

In eclipse,Right click on project name in `Project Explorer > Maven > Update project`. It updates target folder with class files. And now try to re-run `pom.xml`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some context to your answer, as code-only answers do not fulfill the SO standards. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer